# Best validation Structure in java

Tags: java, validation, kotlin

I am working on a validation solution, based on data from DB. Right now the structure in code is covered by if-else statements but I looking for a more complex solution because it is expected the structure will be even more complex like it is now. What is the best approach for complex validation? Just divide it into methods, some validation class solution, or do you have some better idea how to handle something like this?

```
  if (someCondition1) {
        if (!someCondition2) {
            if (!someCondition3) {
                if (!someCondition4) {
                   doSomething();
                } else {
                    doSomething2();
                }
            } else {
                doSomething3();
            }
        } else {
            doSomething4;
        }
    } else {
        doSomething5;
    }
```

Comment: I'd say that depends on the logic. If some conditions make sense when put together, you might want to extract them to a method with a meaningful name. Then you'll have something like `if (isBar() && !isFoo())`...

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of things you can do

1- break those conditional calls into smaller methods

2- Use switch statements when possible

3- Verify your logic to see if all the cases are really necessary or they can be grouped

The code you posted is certainly too nested and will be very hard to debug in the future, so you might want to at least break that into smaller understandable pieces

Answer (score 0):

As a bare minimum, you could flatten the nesting just by re-ordering and flipping some of the conditions:

```
if (!someCondition1) {
    doSomething5()
} else if (someCondition2) {
    doSomething4()
} else if (someCondition3) {
    doSomething3()
} else if (someCondition4) {
    doSomething2()
} else {
    doSomething()
}
```

(That transformation only works because the condition space can be carved up into big chunks like that; if you had a case where both an `if` *and* an `else` branch had to check further conditions, it wouldn't be possible.)

That could then be recast as a Kotlin `when`:

```
when {
    !someCondition1 -> doSomething5()
    someCondition2 -> doSomething4()
    someCondition3 -> doSomething3()
    someCondition4 -> doSomething2()
    else -> doSomething()
}
```

That's doing exactly the same as your original code, but in a more concise way.

Of course, there are many more drastic and high-level refactorings you could do, but I don't think there's a single obvious answer as it would probably depend on the nature and number of the conditions, and how they might change in future.